# Changing the margins of a PDF document in RMarkdown

Tags: css, r-markdown, margin, pagedown

The default resume template from the `pagedown` package is visually not very appealing. There are quite white spaces along the borders, the sidebar is too thick, and the font is not appropriate. I guess I should be knowledgeable in CSS to make changes to manipulate the changes. This is what I have tried so far:

```
 # Manipulating the margins
 p * {
 /* Override default margins*/
 --pagedjs-margin-right: 0.2in;
 --pagedjs-margin-left: 0.2in;
 --pagedjs-margin-top: 0.2in;
 --pagedjs-margin-bottom: 0.2in;
}

# Manipulating the sidebar
:root{
--sidebar-width: 10rem; /* side bar width */
--sidebar-background-color: #e2a2a2;
--decorator-border: 2px solid #a2e2e2; /* change color and thickness of timeline */
}

# Manipulate the font
/* Define the font family here */
body{
font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
```

I have inserted this code chunk after defining YAML. When I play around with the second and third options and knit the file, they work as intended. However, no matter what number I use to change the margins, it remains the same. What should I do?

Comment: Does it mean that margins cannot be used when knitting the file to a PDF but they could be used for HTML? Is there an alternative for PDF? Sorry, I did not understand your reference at the end of your comment. Many thanks!

Comment: I will have a look into them in more depth, thank you both for your answers!